# Jpql syntax error?

Tags: jpa, jpql

```
public List<City> getCIties(String st) {
    String queryString = "SELECT c.cityCollection FROM Country c WHERE c.code =: st";
    Query query3 = em.createQuery(queryString);
    query3.setParameter("number",st);
    List<City> l = query3.getResultList();
    return l;    
}
```

So Country class has a list of cities and my mission is to get a list of all cities in a country, something is wrong with my jpql query. It says "The expression is not a valid conditional expression". For me looks ok because I am returning the city collection from a country with given code.

Comment: you have a space in between ":" and "st". Remove the space

Comment: Damn you great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

your parameter name doesn't seem correct to me. you should set

```
 query3.setParameter("st",st);

public List getCIties(String st) 
{ 
 String queryString = "SELECT c.cityCollection FROM Country c WHERE c.code =: st"; 
Query query3 = em.createQuery(queryString); 
query3.setParameter("st",st); 
List l = query3.getResultList(); 
return l;

}
```

Comment: whatever value should be st the parameter passed to the method